# ProgressView without background color of List view for async loading of content

Tags: listview, swiftui, progress-bar

When the list items are not loading in model variables, the progress view is displayed. This is the correct behavior. But the background is displayed as if `ProgressView()` is an item in the list.

I want to know if there is a way to make the background color of the list disappear only when data is loading and go back to the normal background when data is loaded.

How can I achieve this in the code below?

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {

                    Section(header: Text("People")) {
                        if let people = model.people {
                            ForEach(people, id: \.id) { person in
                                Text(person.name)
                            }
                        } else {
                            ProgressView()
                        }
                    }

                    Section(header: Text("Chat Rooms")) {
                        if let rooms = model.rooms {
                            ForEach((rooms, id: \.id) { room in
                                Text(room.name)
                            }
                        } else {
                            ProgressView()
                        }
                    }

                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer as to why you are getting this behavior is you have made `ProgressView()` an item on your list. If you take away the `if` statement, you can see that `ProgressView()` is actually in the list. If you want it to be a background, you have to set it as the background of whatever view it is to be a background of:

```
Text(person.name)
    .background(
        ProgressView()
    )
```

You can also put logic in the background to show ProgressView() or another view. I am not entirely sure what you want it to look like.